# I got a lot of indexed soft 404 pages they actually dont exixt

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404

I just saw in my WMT that i have a lot of indexed soft 404 pages. They all starts with mysite.com/**index.php/somepage.**. The problem is that i don't have not a single page starts with index.php.

Can someone explain me:
1. Why is those soft 404 pages generated at all when i don't have index.php part on my site?
2. Now the thing that worries me is that i have for example 700 soft 404 pages, and after some time i have 300 and i didn't change anything.
3. Are they harmful for my site?
4. Can this be fixed in using some rewrite rule in Apache to prevent them for been indexed at all?

In my Apache file i have some redirection rules for same pages, but